# Open a *.COM file using stream

Tags: c#, io

Just found myself in need of opening *.COM files in a C# application.
*.COM files are generated by fasm, with assemly code like this one:

> org 100h
>
> jmp start
>
> msg:    db      "Hi", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
>
> start: 
>   mov   dx, msg
>
> ```
>     mov     ah, 09h 
>     int     21h         
>     mov     ah, 0 
>     int     16h
> ```
>
> ret

when opened with textprocessors like Sublime, it's represented that code represented like this:

> eb05 4869 0d0a 24ba 0201 b409 cd21 b400
>
> cd16 c3

I tried to open this file in application with code like this one

```
string COMtext = File.ReadAllText(filename,encoding);

byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(COMtext);
```

When checked with `MessageBox.Show(info[i].ToString("x2"));`
it says, what first byte is EF, 2nd is BF (splitting EB in halfs), then adding one additional byte on 3rd place (BD). After this - everything parsed just as planned.
4th:05, 5th:48 etc.
What do I do wrong and is there any way to fix it without workaround (which one is unclear for me at this stage, because I don't know if would have same behavior or dont)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file as a binary stream, not a text steam. As text it is getting encoded as Unicode surrogates.

Use `File.OpenRead` with a byte array. You can also use `File.ReadAllBytes` but I don't recommend it since a large file will cause an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.What amount of bytes `File.ReadAllBytes` is capable to read? i8088 program code, so it shouldnt be much more than 32kb or such

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` can read up to 2GB of data, IIRC. The problem isn't with the command, but with the fact that for large files it will allocate the array and read all data in one go, which is usually too much memory to be used. However, COM files, in MSDOS at least, are limited to 64k, so I think `File.ReadAllBytes` would be fine.